# Spark dataframe Column content modification

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as shown below `df.show()`:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Col11 |  Col22  | Expend1 | Expend2 | Expend3 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value1 | value1  |     123 |    2264 |      56 |
| Value1 | value2  |     124 |    2255 |      23 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Can I transform the above data frame to the below using some SQL?

```
+--------+---------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| Col11  |  Col22  | Expend1     | Expend2       | Expend3    |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| Value1 | value1  | Expend1:123 | Expend2: 2264 | Expend3:56 |
| Value1 | value2  | Expend1:124 | Expend2: 2255 | Expend3:23 |
+--------+---------+-------------+---------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the idea of `foldLeft` here

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("Value1", "value1", "123", "2264", "56"),
  ("Value1", "value2", "124", "2255", "23")
)).toDF("Col11", "Col22", "Expend1", "Expend2", "Expend3")

//Lists your columns for operation
val cols = List("Expend1", "Expend2", "Expend3")

val newDF = cols.foldLeft(df){(acc, name)  =>
  acc.withColumn(name, concat(lit(name + ":"), col(name)))
}

newDF.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------+-----------+------------+----------+
| Col11| Col22|    Expend1|     Expend2|   Expend3|
+------+------+-----------+------------+----------+
|Value1|value1|Expend1:123|Expend2:2264|Expend3:56|
|Value1|value2|Expend1:124|Expend2:2255|Expend3:23|
+------+------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using simple sql select statement if you want can use udf as well

Ex -> select Col11 , Col22   , 'Expend1:' + cast(Expend1 as varchar(10)) as Expend1, .... from table

Answer (score 0):

```
 val df = Seq(("Value1", "value1",    "123",   "2264",     "56"), ("Value1", "value2",    "124",   "2255",     "23") ).toDF("Col11", "Col22", "Expend1", "Expend2", "Expend3")
 val cols = df.columns.filter(!_.startsWith("Col"))   // It will only fetch other than col% prefix columns

 val getCombineData = udf { (colName:String, colvalue:String) => colName + ":"+ colvalue}
 var in = df 
 for (e <- cols) {
    in = in.withColumn(e, getCombineData(lit(e), col(e)) )
 } 
 in.show

 // results
 +------+------+-----------+------------+----------+
 | Col11| Col22|    Expend1|     Expend2|   Expend3|
 +------+------+-----------+------------+----------+
 |Value1|value1|Expend1:123|Expend2:2264|Expend3:56|
 |Value1|value2|Expend1:124|Expend2:2255|Expend3:23|
 +------+------+-----------+------------+----------+
```